# It takes too long to open mounted network drive from Samba on Windows 7

Tags: windows, samba

The config:

Clients: Windows 7 64-bit,
Server: Samba 3.0.37

Samba socket options: TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE

One samba share is mapped to Windows computers as a network drive. From time to time it takes too long to open the mapped drive (15-20 seconds), in Windows explorer as well as in the console. I believe Windows loses a connection to the network share and tries to restore it from scratch.

So the question is - how to keep the connection alive or to speed up the connection process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low-tech approach - ping it or run a directory listing across it on a reoccurring interval (via a scheduled task from the target system).

Comment: That's of course a solution but maybe there is a more correct way to solve the problem? :)

Comment: You might be able to tune the time-outs on either end - connection idle on Samba or maybe response time-out on the Windows side.

Comment: Yes but where exactly?

Comment: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Comment: You might start by looking at the "deadtime" setting.

Comment: yes, dead time! Copied a config and didn't notice it. Thank you!